macOS Services Menu: Image Not Showing Despite Being in Resources Folder
I am trying to add a custom service to the macOS Services menu, and I want to include an image/icon in the context menu item. I have followed the necessary steps to define the service in the Info.plist file of my macOS app and added the image to the resources folder, but the image still doesn't show up in the Services menu.
Here is my Info.plist service definition:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>NSServices</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>NSMenuItem</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>default</key>
                    <string>Content Credentials</string>
                    <!-- Reference to the image Not Showing!! -->
                    <key>NSImage</key>
                    <string>iconName</string>
                </dict>
                <key>NSMessage</key>
                <string>inspectCredentialsWithPasteboard</string>
                <key>NSPortName</key>
                <string>c2pa-preview</string>
                <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSTextContent</key>
                    <string>FilePath</string>
                </dict>
                <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>public.avi</string>
                    <string>public.avif</string>
                    <string>public.dng</string>
                    <string>public.heic</string>
                    <string>public.heif</string>
                    <string>public.jpeg</string>
                    <string>public.m4a</string>
                    <string>public.mp3</string>
                    <string>public.mpeg-4</string>
                    <string>public.pdf</string>
                    <string>public.png</string>
                    <string>public.svg-image</string>
                    <string>public.tiff</string>
                    <string>public.wav</string>
                    <string>public.webp</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>

I've ensured that the image iconName.png is located inside the resources folder of my Tauri/Rust project, Also check the final .dmg file, Despite this, the image is not appearing in the Services menu.
Thank you in advance.

Verify that the image is included in the application bundle. You can check this by right-clicking on the app bundle, selecting "Show Package Contents," and navigating to the Resources folder.

I can't find the image in the documentation, do you have a link? NSMenuItem lists only the default property.

The NSImage is not mentioned in the properties list of the NSservices:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsservices (check "property list key NSMenuItem Text for a Services menu item."), so I would say that the custom image property is not supported for NSservices. Please check also: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html

The NSImage is not mentioned in the properties list of the NSservices: Apple site
Please check the NSMenuItem entry, only the text can be set:

I would say that the custom image property is not supported for NSservices.
Please check also this link: Apple site too

Try to structure your Info.plist like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">       
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>      
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>app_icon.icns</string>
    <key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        ...
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

and put app_icon.icns in Contents/Resources directory.

Is the question about the app icon or about a custom image in the context (= right click) menu? Please explain what's wrong with the Info.plist in the question and why what should be changed.
